# Do for all but last item in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

G'day all,

I have a javascript array that I am iterating through. I want to, using my for and if loops, do something for each item in the array, with the exception of the last item.

For example, if my array had a list of words in it, and I want to add a dash between each, but not after the last. Is there a simple way to do this without using an array. length and a counter?

Thanks

Comment: `array.join('-')`?

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. Say my array is more complex than I initially stated and I can't change it to a string as it has strings, arrays and other items. What about then?

Comment: well, different use case requires different solutions ... if the array is an array of objects, you can slice it `(0, -1)` and manipulate the objects as required, and the last will not be touched ... e.g. `array.slice(0, -1).forEach(obj => doSomethingToObject)` ... since the objects in the sliced result will be the same objects, then, this is one way to do what you want if the array is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

The `.join(separator)` array method returns a string containing every value of the array it's called on joined by the `separator`.

Since the `separator` is inserted **between** every value, it's not appended to the end.

```js
const words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const dashed = words.join('-');
console.log(dashed); // => 'foo-bar-baz'
```